# Removing BOM characters using Java

Tags: java, vi, byte-order-mark

What needs to happen to a string using Java to be an equivalent of `vi`s

```
:set nobomb
```

Assume that `BOM` comes from the file I am reading.

Comment: Strings in Java do not have BOM... Unless you read from a source which has one

Comment: This is precisely what happens. I am reading the file that happens to have this mark

Comment: Do you at least know what encoding is used (UTF-8, UTF-16 LE/BE)?

Comment: If you have the option just open the file with Notepad++ or SublimeText and resave it without a BOM. Otherwise you'd need to know the encoding type to do it programatically

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Java does not handle BOM properly. In fact Java handles a BOM like every other char.

Found this:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

```
public static final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";

private static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

May be I would use apache IO instead:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html

Comment: `UTF8_BOM` is a wrong name. There is nothing in the BOM that links it to UTF-8. On the contrary, UTF-8 does NOT need the BOM, while UTF-16 MAY (and Microsoft has the bad habit of writing UTF-16 files with a BOM, which often get converted to UTF-8 with BOM by bad tools).

Comment: UTF-8 BOM consists of 3 bytes, not 2.

Answer (score 15):

For UTF-8 the BOM is: 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF