# Removing the BOM character with Java

Tags: java, filereader, byte-order-mark

I am trying to read files using FileReader and write them into a separate file.
These files are UTF-8 encoded, but unfortuantely some of them still contain a BOM.
The relevant code I tried is this:

```
private final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";

 private String removeUTF8BOM(String s)
    {
        if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM))
        {
            s=s.replace(UTF8_BOM, "");
        }
        return s;
    }

    line=removeUTF8BOM(line);
```

But for some reason the BOM is not removed. Is there any other way I can do this with FileReader? I know that there is the BOMInputStream that should work, but I'd rather find a solution using FileReader.

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891578/removing-bom-characters-using-java)?

Answer (score 5):

The class FileReader is an old utility class, that uses the platform encoding. On Windows that is likely *not* UTF-8.

Best to read with another class.

As amusement, and to clarify the error, here a dirty hack, that works for platforms with single byte encodings:

```
private final String UTF8_BOM = new String("\uFEFF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This gets the UTF-8 bytes and makes a String in the current platform encoding.

No need to mention that FileReader is non-portible, dealing only with local files.

Answer (score 2):

### Naive Solution to the question as asked:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final String hasbom = "\uFEFF" + "Hello World!";
    final String nobom = hasbom.charAt(0) == '\uFEFF' ? hasbom.substring(1) : hasbom;
    System.out.println(hasbom.equals(nobom));
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
false
```

### Proper Solution Approach:

You should never program to a `File` based API and instead program against `InputStream/OutputStream` so that your code is portable to different source locations.

This is just an untested example of how you might go about encapsulating this behavior into an `InputStream` to make it transparent.

```
public class BomProofInputStream extends InputStream
{
    private final InputStream is;

    public BomProofInputStream(@Nonnull final InputStream is)
    {
        this.is = is;
    }

    private boolean isFirstByte = true;

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        if (this.isFirstByte)
        {
            this.isFirstByte = false;
            final int b = is.read();
            if ("\uFEFF".charAt(0) != b) { return b; } 
        }
        return is.read();
    }
}
```

#### Found an [full fledged example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835529/177800) with some searching: