# Java compact string equalsIgnoreCase with non-compact string evaluates to false

Tags: java, string, equals

When parsing a `.csv` file I iterate over the file's column headers and see if one of them equals (ignoring case) comparand `id`:

```java
String comparand = "id";
for (String header : headerMap.keySet()) {
   if (header.equalsIgnoreCase(comparand)) {
      recordMap.put("_id", csvRecord.get(header));
   } else {
      recordMap.put(header, csvRecord.get(header));
   }
}
```

The file is read using the `UTF-8` charset:

```java
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The CSV parser library I use is [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/):

```java
CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
   .withDelimiter(delimiter)
   .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
   .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
   .parse(reader);

Map<String, Integer> headerMap = csvParser.getHeaderMap();
```

Somehow the above `equalsIgnoreCase()` evaluates to `false` while both strings have the value `id`.

Observing the debugger shows that the `header` value is a non-compact string (UTF-16) whereas the `comparand` value is a [compact string](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string) (ASCII):

[image: Non-compact string vs. compact string]

Is this default behavior or a bug? How can I make the `equalsIgnoreCase` evaluate to `true` as one would expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `header` value starts with an [UTF-16 BOM `FFFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). Strip the BOM when reading the `header` before comparing it with `comparand`.

Comment: Thanks! I've used this solution to fix my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891671/425238